# Python and tkinter : How do i allow a function in python create an sqlite3 database

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, sqlite, tkinter

The following codes give me an error when i try to submit info to sqlite data base created from function

```
def submit():
   conn = 
   sqlite3.connect('addr.db')
   c = conn.cursor()
   c.execute("INSERT INTO addr.  
   VALUES( ............
   .......
```

I set up the dictionary and end the function with

```
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Anytime i call the function using a tkinter button widget it shows the following error:

**sqlite3.OperatioblError: no such table: addr**

Please is ther something i need to do to allow my function create the database?

Comment: creating a database does not create any tables, you have to create the table first before you can insert into it.

Comment: Thanks very much mickey...  I createdbthe table and ot worked